# Can an electric magnet be a substitude for a magnet to test a metall?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, metals

For instance I have to check if certain metal is a ferromagnetic metal. Can I use an electric magnet instead of non-electric one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that by "electric magnet" you mean an *electromagnet* - i.e. a magnet which uses an active energy source to produce a magnetic field by establishing an electric current.

If so, then yes, you can - magnetic fields are magnetic fields, no matter the nature of their source.